# ngrx help for migrating from rxjs 5 to 6

Tags: rxjs5, ngrx-effects, rxjs6

I am in the middle of migrating my Angular 5 application from using rxjs 5 to rxjs 6. A big part of this is the change from using dot-chaining to using .pipe(). My application is using ngrx, and I am having trouble with Effects. When using rxjs 5, this works.

```
@Effect() public onSave$: void | Observable<void|{}> =
this.actions.ofType<DashboardGroupsActions.Save>(DashboardGroupsActions.SAVE_DASHBOARD_GROUPS)
  .map((action: DashboardGroupsActions.Save) => action.payload)
  .switchMap((payload: DashboardGroups) => {

      return this.api.saveDashboardGroup(payload);
  })
  .catch(() => {

      return Observable.of();
  });
```

Below is what my code looks like after converting the dot-chaining to .pipe(). But now I also get the following error that I can't seem to fix.

"Property 'pipe' does not exist on type '`Actions<Action>`'"

```
import { Observable, pipe, of } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, filter, map, mergeMap, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Action, Store } from '@ngrx/store';
import { Actions, Effect, ofType } from '@ngrx/effects';

@Effect() public onSave$: Observable<{}|Action> = this.actions.pipe(
      ofType<DashboardGroupsActions.Save>(DashboardGroupsActions.SAVE_DASHBOARD_GROUPS),
      map((action: DashboardGroupsActions.Save) => action.payload),
      switchMap((payload: DashboardGroups) => {

          return this.api.saveDashboardGroup(payload);
      }),
      catchError(() => {

          return of({});
      })
  );
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Aside from the migration problem, you have another with your effect. You should read this: https://medium.com/@P_Lessing/handling-errors-in-ngrx-effects-a95d918490d9

Comment: Wow, thanks @cartant for posting that article. For anyone else who sees this, the tldr; version is that if your observable fails, catchError() replaces it with one that succeeds. However, this prevents the first observable from ever emitting again. The catchError should be on the inner observable, and it should be wrapped in a switchMap that way the catchError doesn't replace my original observable.